# Vector with a vector component

Tags: vectors

I need to find the projection of two vectors, $\vec{v}=(1,2,3)$ onto $\vec{u}=\left(\frac{1}{2},\left(\frac{1}{2}, \frac{1}{2\sqrt{2}}\right)\right)$.

What I have to do with $\vec{u}$?

Comment: Your $\vec u$ makes no sense. Is it a 3 dimensional vector?

Comment: and are you familiar with dot product?

Comment: @J.W.Tanner Sure, just I don't know how to use dot product in the vector.

Comment: projection is $\vec{v}\cdot\vec u/|\vec u|$

Comment: I think $u$ is just $(\frac12, \frac12, \frac1{2\sqrt2})$. However, you should add more context..